# 3DES library for encryption and decryption in iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing an iphone application which needs the 3des encryption
Is there any library available

Comment: I hope you're not using triple DES for anything serious :-(

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Common Cryptor handles 3DES. See [CCCryptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/CCCryptor.3cc.html).